# Virtual Function Signature Mismatch and its behavior

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, virtual-functions

I am looking at an example case of the behavior of virtual functions. Given this test code, I have a few questions as to its behavior.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int x)
    {
        cout << "In A Constructor" << endl;
        print();
    }
    ~A(){
        cout << "In A Destructor" << endl;
        delete _val;
    }
    virtual void print() { cout << "A." << endl; }
private:
    char* _val;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B(int x, int y) : A(x)
    {
        _dVal = new char[y];
        cout << "In B Constructor 1" << endl;
        print();
    }
    B() : A(0)
    {
        _dVal = new char[1];
        cout << "In B Constructor 2" << endl;
        print();
    }
    ~B(){
        cout << "In B Destructor" << endl;
        delete _dVal;
    }
    void print() { cout << "B" << endl; }
private:
    char* _dVal;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A* p1 = new B();
    p1->print();
    delete p1;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
In A Constructor
A.
In B Constructor 2
B
B
In A Destructor
```

1) Why is print called for class B if class A is the only one denoting it as a virtual function and it is being called by dereference (->)?
2) Why is the destructor for B never being called if the constructor is in fact being called?

Comment: If the function is virtual in the base class, it is virtual in all derived classes as well. Ditto for the destructor.

Comment: One question per question please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Why is print called for class B if class A is the only one denoting it as a virtual function and it is being called by dereference (->)?

That's what virtual functions are supposed to do. The pointer `p1` is of type `A*` but it's pointing to an object of type `B` in fact. And this dynamic binding only happens when a derived class is handled using pointer or reference to the base class.

Also note that the overriding function in the derived class is also [virtual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#In_detail) (whether or not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration).

> 2) Why is the destructor for B never being called if the constructor is in fact being called?

The destructor of `B` is not called because you're not declaring the destructor of base class (i.e. `A::~A`) as [virtual destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#Virtual_destructor). The behavior is undefined for this case. The constructor of `B` is called because you construct `B` explicitly by `new B()`.

Comment: Interesting. Since the behavior is undefined, does that mean that _dVal from class B would become an oprhan and cause a memory leak then?

Comment: @user49096 From the result you observed, yes. Note that it's undeterminate, anything is possible.

Comment: @user49096 "_Since the behavior is undefined, does that mean_" no, it means what happens is not defined, undefined, unknown...